# Not able to open attachments in email aosp stock app

Tags: android

Can someone suggests the correct source code for email client stock AOSP which can correctly sync all gmail folders and also attachments are being able to open.

I tried building an apk with the src from master branch  at
`git` by cloning:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Email

```
06-10 15:38:59.187  8570  8647 W Email   : Query returning null for uri: content://com.android.email.provider/uirefresh/98 selection: null
06-10 15:38:59.348  8570  8633 I ConvCursor: *** ConversationCursor pre-loading took 0ms n=0
06-10 15:38:59.432  8570  8570 D StrictMode: StrictMode policy violation; ~duration=12 ms: android.os.StrictMode$StrictModeDiskWriteViolation: policy=65543 violation=1
06-10 15:38:59.432  8570  8570 D StrictMode:    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onWriteToDisk(StrictMode.java:1253)
06-10 15:38:59.432  8570  8570 D StrictMode:    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.applyBlockGuardPolicy(SQLiteConnection.java:1043)
06-10 15:38:59.432  8570  8570 D StrictMode:    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForChangedRowCount(SQLiteConnection.java:731)
06-10 15:38:59.432  8570  8570 D StrictMode:    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForChangedRowCount(SQLiteSession.java:754)
06-10 15:38:59.432  8570  8570 D StrictMode:    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeUpdateDelete(SQLiteStatement.java:64)
06-10 15:38:59.432  8570  8570 D StrictMode:    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.updateWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1579)
06-10 15:38:59.432  8570  8570 D StrictMode:    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.update(SQLiteDatabase.java:1525)
06-10 15:38:59.432  8570  8570 D StrictMode:    at com.android.email.provider.EmailProvider$6.onRefreshCompleted(EmailProvider.java:5970)
06-10 15:38:59.432  8570  8570 D StrictMode:    at com.android.email.provider.RefreshStatusMonitor$RemoveRefreshStatusRunnable.run(RefreshStatusMonitor.java:147)
06-10 15:38:59.432  8570  8570 D StrictMode:    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
06-10 15:38:59.432  8570  8570 D StrictMode:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
06-10 15:38:59.432  8570  8570 D StrictMode:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
06-10 15:38:59.432  8570  8570 D StrictMode:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6121)
06-10 15:38:59.432  8570  8570 D StrictMode:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
06-10 15:38:59.432  8570  8570 D StrictMode:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
06-10 15:38:59.432  8570  8570 D StrictMode:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
```

Comment: What is your exact issue and question ? Clarify in detail.

Comment: Not able to open pdf , word or png attachments in the mails in email client aosp app.

Comment: By this [one](https://github.com/open-keychain/open-keychain/issues/290)

Comment: Have you checked the link?

Comment: I am not able to find the exact solution in this link.I tried installing the open-keychain apk in the device and then tried opening attachments in email client.Did not work.

Comment: Are you able to pull all code from repository ?

Comment: Code from open-keychain repository? yes able to pull all code